# Workflow Foundation - persistence extra data

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I've created a small application using Workflow Foundation and ASP.NET.
I've multiple steps with human interaction in a FlowChart.
For each steps of the workflow where the persistence is involved (= before each human interaction), I would like to save/update an extra parameter like a "worklow object" containing few string properties.

I've looked into the stored extensibility solution (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726.aspx) but I'm not able to get it up and running: the table "InstancePromotedPropertiesTable" of the database used for the persistance is not updated and is completely empty.

Is there any specific action not mentioned on MSDN?

Is there any other solution to attach to the workflow an extra custom data that we can read/write during or before the resume?

Based on the documentation available on MSDN, here is a sample of my code:

Creation of the workflow application:

```
        private WorkflowApplication CreateWorkflow<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary) where T : Activity, new()
    {
        WorkflowApplication workflowApplication;

        if (dictionary.Any())
        {
            workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new T(), dictionary);
        }
        else
        {
            workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new T());
        }

        workflowApplication.InstanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(InstanceStoreConnectionString);

        workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = (e) =>
        {
            return PersistableIdleAction.Persist;
        };

        workflowApplication.Completed = (e) =>
        {
            _isCompleted = true;
            _instanceUnloaded.Set();
        };
        workflowApplication.Idle = (e) =>
        {
            _instanceUnloaded.Set();
        };

        workflowApplication.Unloaded = (e) =>
        {

        };

        DocumentStatusExtension documentStatusExtension = new DocumentStatusExtension();
        workflowApplication.Extensions.Add(documentStatusExtension);
        return workflowApplication;
    }
```

The execute method of the step before going to idle:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var bookmarkName = context.GetValue(StepName);

        context.GetExtension<DocumentStatusExtension>().DocumentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        context.GetExtension<DocumentStatusExtension>().UserName = "John Smith";
        context.GetExtension<DocumentStatusExtension>().ApprovalStatus = "Approved";
        context.GetExtension<DocumentStatusExtension>().LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Create a bookmark allows the persistance in the DB
        context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkName, new BookmarkCallback(this.Continue));
    }
```

And the PersistenceParticipant class where the Promote method is called:

```
public class DocumentStatusExtension : PersistenceParticipant
{
    public string DocumentId;
    public string ApprovalStatus;
    public string UserName;
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime;

    protected override void CollectValues(out IDictionary<XName, object> readWriteValues, out IDictionary<XName, object> writeOnlyValues)
    {
        //All these properties are passed to SqlWorkflowInstanceStore by the persistence framework through the SaveWorkflowCommand.InstanceData collection.

        XNamespace xNS = XNamespace.Get("http://contoso.com/DocumentStatus");

        readWriteValues = new Dictionary<XName, object>();
        readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("UserName"), this.UserName);
        readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("ApprovalStatus"), this.ApprovalStatus);
        readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("DocumentId"), this.DocumentId);
        readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("LastModifiedTime"), this.LastUpdateTime);

        writeOnlyValues = null;

        SqlWorkflowInstanceStore store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceStoreConnectionString"]);

        List<XName> variantProperties = new List<XName>()
        {
            xNS.GetName("UserName"),
            xNS.GetName("ApprovalStatus"),
            xNS.GetName("DocumentId"),
            xNS.GetName("LastModifiedTime")
        };

        store.Promote("DocumentStatus", variantProperties, null);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think we'd need to see your code to diagnose why the table is not being populated, but have you considered just handling the WorkflowRuntime.WorkflowPersisted event and writing your assoicated parameters explicitly?  Or overriding the Persistence Service?

Comment: I've added the sample of my code in the initial request